# Refused connection python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

## My error

I get SOMETIMES the next message when I compile my programme:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cliente1.py", line 129, in <module>
    sTCP.connect((iplista[y],int(portlista[y])))  #SE CONECTA N VECES
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The strange thing about this is that the message is not shown every single time, just the most of the times because sometimes it works well.
Here you have an example in which the message is not shown:
[image]

## What I would like it to do

I would like it to work properly, I don't really know why the connection is refused, if someone could tell me I 'd be thankful

## The code

```
#importar librerias
import socket
import sys      #para cerrar el sistema
import os       #para saber tamanio del fichero
import md5      #para hacer huella de seguridad
import time

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

if len(sys.argv) != 2: #el nombre del programa cuenta como argumento
    print("Error. Uso: python %s ./fichero" % (sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit()

nombre_fichero = sys.argv[1]   #nombre del fichero dado en los argumentos

#creacion de sockets




#leemos el archivo config.txt (OJO CON LA RUTA)
try:
    configtxt = open('./config.txt')   #puedes poner conffig para un fichero vacio
    #data1 = configtxt.readline() puedes indicarle el numero de bytes que lea

except:
    print("Error, no hay servidores o ficheros de configuracion", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

#almacenamos las lineas del fichero en una tabla
# Splits the element by "\n"
lineas = configtxt.readlines()


#Print List of Lines in your File
#print(lines)

#Print Number of Lines in your File
#print(len(lines))
numero_de_lineas = len(lineas)
#Access Second Line in your file
#print(lineas[0])

#print(numero_de_lineas)

check = 1   #si vale 0 no hay lineas en config.txt

try:
    linea1 = lineas[0]

except IndexError:
    check = 0


if check == 0:   #si esta vacia la primera linea de ./config.txt :ERROR
    print("Error, no hay servidores o ficheros de configuracion")
    sys.exit()
else:
    #resto del programa
    try:   #existe el fichero que le he dado en los argumentos?
        fichero = open(nombre_fichero)
    except IOError as error1: #No existe
        print("Error. Fichero %s inexistente:" % nombre_fichero)
        print(error1)
        sys.exit()


    #resto del programa si todo lo anterior va bien
    #le enviamos un mensaje al 1er server con el nombre del fichero y su tamanio
    #para saber tamanio en bytes: os.stat("file").st_size
    tamanio_fichero_int = os.stat(nombre_fichero).st_size
    #convertimos ese tamanio_fichero_int a str porque sino no deja concatenar
    tamanio_fichero_str = str(tamanio_fichero_int)
    #concatenamos nombre_fichero y tamanio_fichero
    mensaje1 = nombre_fichero + " " + tamanio_fichero_str   #mensaje a enviar listo

    iplista = list()      #creamos las listas
    portlista = list()
    sUDP = list()

    for x in range (0,numero_de_lineas):
        ip , port = lineas[x].split()

        iplista.append(ip)          #anadirmos a la lista las ips
        portlista.append(port)      #anadimos a la lista los puertos

    #tupla = (str(iplista[0]),int(portlista[0]))
    #sUDP.sendto(mensaje1,tupla)
    #print(tupla)

    time_out = 3
    time_out_TCP = 10
    counter = 1
    reintentar = 0   #si hay que reintentar una transmision , reintentar vale 1


    y = 0  #interacciones
    contenido_fichero = fichero.read()  #lo que hay dentro de ./fichero.txt

    while y != numero_de_lineas:
        print "Interaccion numero", y
        try: #tenemos que crear el socket tcp en cada interaccion porque sino ya esta en uso
            sUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)     #UDP
            sTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    #TCP
        except socket.error :
            print "Error al crear socket TCP"
            sys.exit()

        if reintentar == 1:
            print y
            reintentar = 0


        tupla = (str(iplista[y]),int(portlista[y]))

        sUDP.sendto(mensaje1,tupla)
        try:

            sUDP.settimeout(time_out)
            respuesta1 , address1 = sUDP.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)

            #si todo va bien tengo respuesta1
            #print(respuesta1) #recibo ni ok ni no
            if (respuesta1 == "ok"):

                sTCP.connect((iplista[y],int(portlista[y])))  #SE CONECTA N VECES

                sTCP.send(contenido_fichero)
                try:

                    sTCP.settimeout(time_out_TCP) #esperamos 10 segundos
                    respuesta2 = sTCP.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    #LIBERAMOS LA CONEXION TCP

                    #print(respuesta2) #recibo transferdone
                    #si recibe respuesta1 y respuesta2 paramos
                    #empezamos con el calculo de la huella con el server aceptado iplista[y],portlista[y]
                    huella_md5 = md5.new() #creamos la huella
                    huella_md5.update(contenido_fichero) #actualicamos su contenido (le podemos meter mas strings despues)
                    huella_md5_calculada = huella_md5.hexdigest() #huella en string



                    sUDP.sendto(huella_md5_calculada,tupla)
                    try:
                        sUDP.settimeout(time_out_TCP) #porque son 10 segundos
                        respuesta3 , address3 = sUDP.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)

                        if respuesta3 == "md5sum ok":
                            print "Copia de fichero en servidor",iplista[y],"correcta"

                        if respuesta3 == "md5sum error":
                            print "Error en la copia del fichero en el servidor",iplista[y],"Se vuelve a intentar" #REINTENTAR
                            reintentar = 1



                    except socket.timeout:
                        print "Error en la copia del fichero en el servidor",iplista[y],". Finalizado el intento"


                except socket.timeout:
                    print "Error en la transferencia con el servidor",str(iplista[y])
            if respuesta1 == "no":
                print "Error. El servidor",iplista[y],"no acepta el fichero"

        except socket.timeout:
            print "Error: no hay respuesta por parte del servidor",  iplista[y] , "en el puerto", portlista[y]
            #if y == (numero_de_lineas-1):  #-1 porque para y el cero cuenta
                #sys.exit()  #si todos fallaron al conectar udp nos salimos



        #fin del bucle


        sUDP.close()

        sTCP.close()

        if (reintentar != 1):
            y = y+1             #si no se reintenta la conexion pasamos al siguiente server









#no olvidar cerrar sockets y ficheros
fichero.close()
configtxt.close()
```

Comment: Use a try-except block?

Comment: but the only thing I can achieve using try-except is to capture the error... the error will still be there, tell me if I am wrong @t.m.adam

Comment: Yes, but what else can you do when the server refuses connection? Just catch the exception and close the socket.

Comment: all right! thank you very much! You gave me the idea to let the code run just if the connection is right. I'll let you know if works :) @t.m.adam

Comment: Cool! If you figure it out consider posting an answer, it might be useful to others.

Comment: Well, havent got the solution yet, but I'll post it as soon as I solve the problem @t.m.adam